# How to display (&#9776;) on mobiles browsers?

Tags: html, css, character-encoding

I'm using (`&#9776;`) and it appears on computer even when I reduce browsers width but when I check it from my mobile browser it doesn't appear, why is that? and how to show it? Is there is another way to create or use something like this icon that would work on mobile phones?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
&#8801;
```

mobile browsers are more able to use this unicode character! Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

just create this hamburger with css and html

HTML:

```css
.hamburger-icon {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 19px 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.hamburger-icon span {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.hamburger-icon span:last-child {
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<label class="hamburger-icon">
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
</label
```